# ASP.NET MVC3 Route - example.com/blog/projects to example.com/projects

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an `ActionResult` in my Blog controller that is returning all the projects called `Projects`, but my URL looks like `example.com/blog/projects`, I want to set up route to make it look like `example.com/projects`.

Is it possible? And if it is then how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register route following way Global.asax and put this as a first route

```
routes.MapRoute("Projects", "Projects" , new { controller="blog" , action="Projects" });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I know how to do that for other needs as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a route to your Global.asax.cs file, such as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Projects", // Route name
    "Projects/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Projects", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

So it looks something like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Projects", // Route name
        "Projects/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Blog", action = "Projects", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

Make sure you put your new route above the default one otherwise yours will never be hit.